# Array restructure in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, structure

I have a php array that looks like this:

```
    Array
    (
       [0] => Array
              (
                [0] => name_first
                [1] => name_second
                [2] => age
              )

       [1] => Array
              (
                [0] => firstname1
                [1] => surname1
                [2] => age1
              )

       [2] => Array
              (
                [0] => firstname2
                [1] => surname2
                [2] => age2
              )
    )
```

and I want to use the first three values (they do change) and if there is an underscored one (like the name_first and name_second in this example), re-structure the array into this:

```
    Array
    (
      [0] => Array
             (
               [name] => Array
                         (
                           [first] => firstname1
                           [second] => surname1
                         )
               [age] => age1
             )

      [1] => Array
             (
               [name] => Array
                         (
                           [first] => firstname2
                           [second] => surname2
                         )
               [age] => age2
             )
    )
```

I have been working on this for 2 days now but I am having trouble coming up with a solution to this so my question is: **How can I achieve this in an efficient way?**

Comment: What did you try? What were the inefficient solutions? Did you try loop, array_map?

Comment: It's just a loop and overwriting the indexed array with an associative array.

Comment: I was close to achieving but never actually achieved the structure intended hence I am asking the question here. I couldn't come up with a working algorithm to achieve this.

Comment: @Calle I didn't try array_map I am looking in to it, can you provide a simple example to achieve this with array_map ?

Comment: come on guys I really need your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated answer due to your comments... here's the working code:

```
$input = array(
    array(
        "name_first",
        "name_second",
        "age"
    ),
    array(
        "firstname1",
        "surname1",
        "age1"
    ),
    array(
        "firstname2",
        "surname2",
        "age2"
    )
);

function restructure($input) {
  $output = array();
  $a_length = count($input);
  for ($a = 0; $a < $a_length; $a++) { // Loop through child arrays
    $b_length = count($input[$a]);
    for ($b = 0; $b < $b_length; $b++) { // Loop through child array's properties
      if ($a) {
        setValue($output[$a - 1], $input[0][$b], $input[$a][$b]); // See function below
      } else {
        // First child array of $input
        $input[$a][$b] = explode("_", $input[$a][$b]); // Create an array of indexes out of each property.
      }
    }
  }
  return $output;
}

function setValue(&$arr, $indices, $value) { //$arr passed by reference
    $count = count($indices);
    if ($count == 1) { // Check if more than one index (value needs to be nested)
        $arr[$indices[0]] = $value; // Apply value to array
    }
    else {
        $index = array_shift($indices); // Remove first index from array
        if (!is_array($arr[$index])) { // Create an array at this index if it doesn't exist
          $arr[$index] = array();
        }
        setValue($arr[$index], $indices, $value); // Recursively call function passing the current index as reference.
    }
}

print_r(restructure($input));
```

Output:

```
Array ( 
  [0] => Array ( 
    [name] => Array ( 
      [first] => firstname1 
      [last] => surname1 
    ) 
    [age] => age1 
  ) 
  [1] => Array ( 
    [name] => Array ( 
      [first] => firstname2 
      [last] => surname2 
    ) 
    [age] => age2 
  ) 
)
```

It takes your first child array as a map of index names. To make a value nested put an underscore in it's name e.g.

```
array(
  array(
    "one_two_three",
    "hello"
  ),
  array(
    "first val",
    "second val"
  )
)
```

would create the following structure:

```
Array(
  [0] => Array(
    [one] => Array(
      [two] => Array(
        [three] => "first val"
      )
    )
    [hello] => "second val"
  )
)
```

Comment: yes this does what I want but my field names are not always the same, so I have to use the names (first three values in my example) to achieve this. how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
$result[]=array('name'=>array('firstname'=>$firstName,'lastname'=>$lastName),'age'=>$age);
```

So lets say we have an array of names and ages like:

```
$persons=array(
    [0]=>array('name'=>'Fredrick cheeseton','age'=>'23')
    [1]=>array('name'=>'Bob Scandal','age'=>'102')
    ['random key to show this doesn\'t matter']=array('name'=>'Uncle Jeff','age'=>'1')
);
```

Let's now process this into the `$result` array like you've specified:

```
foreach($persons as $person){
    //leaving the array key blank suggests an auto acceding integer.
    $name=explode(" ",$person['name']);//spliting the name into two parts using the ' '(space)
    $result[]=array('name'=>array('firstName'=>$name[0],'lastName'=>$name[1]),'age'=>$person['age']);
}
if(isset($result))?var_dump($result):'Result was never declared';
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, the result is what I am trying to achieve but my initial array duesn't have the full name that can be exploded but instead I have 2 fields named name_first and name_second and want to have `[name] => [first] => fredrick
                                       [second] => cheeseton`

Comment: @user1918451 Just change the key names/ Where I've used 'firstName' change it to 'first'. Then with the explode just ignore it and replace the `$name[0]` with `$name_first` etc

Comment: I am having trouble changing the code, the problem is my initial array is not always in the same structure but it contains underscored keys, if this is the case I want to do what you have suggested but the field names are not always the same(can be age can be year or may be used for different data so I want this to be dynamic)